# Perl Script for conky. Permissions problem

Tags: linux, permissions, perl

I wrote a simple perl script to change conky background and download some data from the web. This script works fine when I start conky by myself, but it doesn't work when I restart my system and conky starts automatically. I don't know where the problem can be, since the file has r-x permissions for all groups and users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First guess, your script calls some other command and system startup has a different PATH environment variable.

It would be really helpful if you could post the script.  Otherwise, all anybody can do for you is guess.

Comment: Yes, it is my fault. Just looked at it again and the first thing I found was `my $path=$ENV{"HOME"}...`
Thanks.